# How do I evaluate this : $\int_{0}^{\infty} \ln \left( 1 + \frac{a^{2}}{x^{2}}\right)\ dx $ for $a > 0$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

How do I evaluate this integral if I suppose that $a > 0$

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \ln \left( 1 + \frac{a^{2}}{x^{2}}\right)\ \mathrm{d}x .$$

For $a=2$ I got $2\pi$ I think the result will be $a\pi$.

Comment: i think it work by part

Comment: You are correct about the result of the integral for every $a$, i.e., $I = a\pi$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [an answer by rae306 on Art of Problem Solving](http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/u240689h1081981p4770740):

> Using integration by parts:
>   $$\int_0^\infty \ln\left(1+\frac{a^2}{x^2}\right)\,dx\,\,\begin{bmatrix}u=\ln\left(1+\frac{a^2}{x^2}\right)& du=\frac{\frac{-2a^2}{x}}{x^2+a^2}\,dx \\ dv=dx& v=x\end{bmatrix}\\=\underbrace{\left.x\cdot \ln\left(1+\frac{a^2}{x^2}\right)\right|_0^{\infty}}_{L}+\underbrace{\int_0^{\infty}\frac{2a^2}{x^2+a^2}\,dx}_{I}$$
>   $$I=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{2a^2}{x^2+a^2}\,dx=\left.2a^2\cdot\frac{1}{a}\arctan\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)\right\vert_0^\infty=2a\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}=\pi a$$
>   We now have to show that $L=0$:
>   $$\lim_{x\to\infty}x\cdot\ln\left(1+\frac{a^2}{x^2}\right)=\lim_{x\to\infty}x\left(\frac{a^2}{x^2}-\frac{\left(\frac{a^2}{x^2}\right)^2}{2}+\frac{\left(\frac{a^2}{x^2}\right)^3}{3}-\frac{\left(\frac{a^2}{x^2}\right)^4}{4}+\ldots\right)\\=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{a^2}{x}-\frac{a^4}{2x^3}+\frac{a^6}{3x^5}-\frac{a^8}{4x^7}+\ldots=0$$ by using the series expansion.
>   $$\lim_{x\to0}x\cdot\ln\left(1+\frac{a^2}{x^2}\right)=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{a^2}{x^2}\right)}{\frac{1}{x}}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{\frac{2a^2}{x}}{x^2+a^2}}{\frac{1}{x^2}}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2a^2 x}{x^2+a^2}=0$$ using L'Hôpital's Rule.
>   Therefore $$\int_0^\infty \ln\left(1+\frac{a^2}{x^2}\right)\,dx= a\pi$$
>   $\square$

Answer (score 23):

Let $I(a)$ be the integral

$$I(a)\equiv \int_0^{\infty}\log\left(1+\frac{a^2}{x^2}\right)dx$$

Taking a derivative with respect to $a$ reveals that

$$\begin{align}
I'(a)&=\frac{d}{da}\int_0^{\infty}\log\left(1+\frac{a^2}{x^2}\right)dx\\\\
&=2a\int_0^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^2+a^2}\\\\
&=\pi
\end{align}$$

Integrating shows that $I(a)=\pi a +C$.  Now, inasmuch as $I(0)=0$, $C=0$ and we find

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\int_0^{\infty}\log\left(1+\frac{a^2}{x^2}\right)dx=\pi a}$$

Comment: This is the most elegant answer I have ever seen! Just beautiful!

Comment: @CauchytheDog Wow!  Thank you!  I cannot tell you how much that means.  I had surgery (4th one is a little more than a year) two weeks ago and have been at home recovering.  You just made my day and weekend!

Comment: @Dr. MV hope you're on the mend. This was one of the physicists Richard Feynman's favourite tricks, differentiating under the integral sign. Compared with the integration by parts approach we see just how powerful a method this is, with a very beautiful illustration of it here.

Comment: @danielbuck Thank you!  And I am doing much better.  Richard was amazing.

Answer (score 9):

$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\log\left(1+\frac{a^2}{x^2}\right)\,dx = a\int_{0}^{+\infty}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\,dx $$
then by setting $x=\tan\theta$ we have:

$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\,dx = -2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\log\sin\theta}{\cos^2\theta}\,d\theta=2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cot(\theta)\tan(\theta)\,d\theta=\color{red}{\pi},$$
where the last step follows from integration by parts.